Different Behaviors in Go Race Condition Scenarios
I'm trying to understand why two similar pieces of code behave differently. Both snippets create a large number of goroutines that try to append to the same slice concurrently, which I understand is a race condition. However, the first snippet panics, while the second one doesn't.
Here are the snippets:
Snippet 1:
package main

func main() {
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        var arr []int
        go func() {
            arr = append(arr, 1)
        }()
        go func() {
            arr = append(arr, 1)
        }()
    }
}

Snippet 2:
package main

func main() {
    var arr []int
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        go func() {
            arr = append(arr, 1)
        }()
        go func() {
            arr = append(arr, 1)
        }()
    }
}

Can anyone help me understand why the first snippet panics but the second one doesn't? Thanks in advance for your help!

"which I understand is a race condition". Okay. You understand that this is a race condition. A race condition means: anything can happen. There is no point in reasoning about racy code as it has no defined semantics. It is just broken.

I agree with Volker's sentiment -- for practical programming there's no value in understanding what's happening, only that you've done something wrong. But I think it's still a valid technical question to understand why one version of the code is panic-ing and the other not, and such a question may lead to a greater understanding of potential concurrency pitfalls. But if you want an answer, it'd be helpful for more detail -- for example can you provide the panic that you see?

I expect the panic is due to simultaneous updates to a nil slice, perhaps with one goroutine seeing cap=1 before the pointer is updated. In snippet 2 where there's only one slice there's only one chance to get this, but in snippet 1 there's a chance for every loop iteration.

The second snippet is more likely to panic because you are read/write the same variable concurrently on multiple goroutines without proper locking
But the first one is also problematic.
Since your goroutines are “trivial” you may never trigger a panic. But the race condition detector can find
I would suggest:

read about -race option
Use a waitgroup to force run over all goroutines and wait before your program finishes
Use a channel to sync the start of the goroutines on each loop


for … {
ch := make(chan struct{},0)
go func(){
  <- ch
  // logic
}()
go …

close(ch) // should trigger both goroutines “at same time”
}

Enjoy

One could guess.
In you first example you spawn a lot of goroutine pairs growing the same (nil) slice, so there is a high change that one routine sees the unfinished results from the other, which means a partially initialized arr slice.
In the second example you mostly write to the same slice, so concurrent goroutines overwrite data from the other, but when one routine appends an element and sets the new length to 5, then the other overwrites an element and sets the length to 4 you just have invalid data, but no crash.
In both cases you have invalid data, but it is easier to detect in the first case, due to the crash, while passing -race flag detects the second condition.
Be aware that the race detector does not detect all data races and results of races is different on different CPU architectures, so be careful that the assumed behavior is specified in the documentation.
